# System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to work with a tcp it service that requires me to send an ID as string. I got the method below from a sample code. 
I the problem is when i enter strings with 4 chars numbers like "4000", "2000", "3000" the method works but when i enter strings with less that 4 chars "1", "20", or "300"
it returns

> System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check
>   destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.

```
 public byte[] prepNetworkStreamBuffer(string reqiiredID) {
        byte[] id = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqiiredID);
        int l = id.Length;
        byte[] idb = BitConverter.GetBytes(System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(l));

        byte[] buff = new byte[1 + 1 + id.Length + l];
        buff[0] = 0;
        buff[1] = (byte)VerificationServiceCommands.addIDtoAFIS;
        idb.CopyTo(buff, 1 + 1);
        id.CopyTo(buff, 1 + 1 + idb.Length);

        return buff;
    }
```

Comment: the Exception occors at:
 id.CopyTo(buff, 1 + 1 + idb.Length);

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the buffer length is

```
1 + 1 + id.Length + l
```

When it should be

```
1 + 1 + idb.Length + l
        ^^^
```

The best way to check this problem would be to fire up the debugger and take a look at the length of `buff`.

Comment: By padding the string with empty string and ensuring that its always 4 characters, it seem to solve the problem..

`byte[] id = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tId.PadRight(4,' '));`

Comment: @user1576148 That will certainly be the case, because `idb` will pretty much always be four bytes long.  When determining the buffer length, is there a reason why you use `id`'s length twice instead of using `idb` and `id` lengths?

Answer (score 0):

You're copying `idb` and `id` to `buff`, which is only of size `2*id.Length + 2`.

So when `id` is only of size 3, your `buff` is too small to fit `idb`, which is of size 4.

You want:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[1 + 1 + id.Length + idb.Length];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool TryGetArray(ref SomeObject[] source )
    {
        try
        {
            var localSource = new List<SomeObject>{new SomeObject(), new SomeObject()};

            var temp = new SomeObject[localSource.Count + source.Length];
            Array.Copy(source, temp, source.Length);
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(localSource.ToArray(), 0, temp, source.Length, localSource.Count);
            source = temp;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```